# Installed IDA 7.0 Freeware -- no debugger, is that installed separately?

Tags: ida, debuggers

After setting up a home lab and installing the latest IDA 7.0 freeware, I don't see the debugger submenu I was expecting -- I've only used it in an academic setting before and it came pre-configured for me.

Is the debugger a separate add-in that I need to install/enable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The freeware version comes without such features as a debugger.
According to the [freeware page](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_freeware.shtml) on Hex-Rays site:

> The freeware version of IDA v7.0 has the following limitations:
>
> ...
>
> - lacks support for many processors, file formats, debugging etc...

**edit:**

IDA freeware is now released *with* the debugging feature available since March 2019. The above quote no longer includes "debugging" on the free download page linked above.